# XML::Twig: is parsefile() more efficient than parse()?

Tags: xml, perl, xml-twig

I've written a fairly basic webapp in Perl and it processes XML files using [`XML::Twig`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aTwig).  These XML files are fairly large and complex, so I'm deliberately using the chunk by chunk varient of `XML::Twig` rather than the "load it all at once" method.

However, this webapp completely crashes and dies if I load in a large XML document, even when using the chunking method.  I couldn't get any clues as to why this was happening, because the webapp is hosted on a shared server with 1and1.co.uk, and I can't see the Apache error log file.  Even when wrapping the calls in an `eval{}` block, I couldn't catch it from dying.  Annoyingly, it works fine on my development server at home, so I couldn't reproduce the problem.

To get it working, I made a change so that instead of using the `parse()` method and passing in a scalar containing the entire XML, I wrote the XML to a file, then used `parsefile( $filename )` instead.  When I made that change, it worked.

I'm just a bit confused by this, tbh, and I attempted to find out via the wonder of Google if `parsefile()` is indeed more efficient that `parse()`, but failed to locate anything.  Does anyone happen to know?

Answer (score 2):

Look at the source. They are the same thing.

In [XML::Twig](https://www.metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aTwig) `parsefile` is just an extended `XML::Parser::parsefile` (the superclass):

```
sub parsefile
  { my $t= shift;
    if( -f $_[0] && ! -s $_[0]) { return _checked_parse_result( undef, "empty file '$_[0]'"); }
    $t= eval { $t->SUPER::parsefile( @_); };
    return _checked_parse_result( $t, $@);
  }
```

In [XML::Parser](https://www.metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aParser), `parsefile` is just a wrapper around `parse`:

```
sub parsefile {
  my $self = shift;
  my $file = shift;
  local(*FILE);
  open(FILE, $file) or  croak "Couldn't open $file:\n$!";
  binmode(FILE);
  my @ret;
  my $ret;

  $self->{Base} = $file;

  if (wantarray) {
    eval {
      @ret = $self->parse(*FILE, @_);
    };
  }
  else {
    eval {
      $ret = $self->parse(*FILE, @_);
    };
  }
  my $err = $@;
  close(FILE);
  die $err if $err;

  return unless defined wantarray;
  return wantarray ? @ret : $ret;
}
```

Comment: I may be misunderstanding your answer, but that's not comparing XML::Twig's parsefile() and parse()?  It's comparing two methods in XML::Parser?  And let's say that one is indeed just a wrapper around the other... why would one crash and another work with the same large XML file?  This is what is confusing me.

Comment: The top code is from XML::Twig. The bottom code is from XML::Parser, the super class. You haven't shown us any code. You could be doing all sort of other things that aren't good.

Answer (score -1):

I am sure 1 and 1 allow you access to the Apache log file as it is a vital tool for debugging CGI and web apps such as yours. Give them a shout and ask them how to do it.

If your XML files are large then it spoils the point of using `XML::Twig` in chunk mode. It also seems likely that your app is failing on the server because it has exceeded its memory quota. Again, a call to your web hosting company will tell you whether this is the case.

How does your XML get into memory in the first place? If you are slurping it into memory from an XML file then just leave the fix as it is and get `XML::Twig` to read directly from the file. If you are fetching the XML from a remote URL then remember that `XML::Twig` has a `parseurl` method which will avoid fetching the data to a local file. I can't think of another likely source so you will have to explain.

Comment: 1and1 don't give access to the error log file.  I don't see how parsing the XML in chunks is spoiling the point of using XML::Twig, since that's the point of using it.  1and1 won't just give me extra memory; hell, these guys refuse to deploy standard packages on their debian servers (such as libxml-twig-perl!).  As for the XML, it's downloaded from a URL and stored to disk; this needs to happen as the XML is so large, the server crashes with large (+5MB) XML files when attempting to hold it in memory - I kid you not.

Comment: Then you have my sympathies: restricting access to the error log is bizarre! I meant keeping the entire XML file in memory spoils the point of chunk processing as you have used a vast amount of memory already. I thought you were dumping your in-memory XML to a file and using `XML::Twig` to process it from there. Since it is coming from a remote URL you can avoid holding it locally altogether and use `parseurl` instead of `parsefile`.